# SAS function to find value with given probability

Tags: sas, statistics, probability

I have a small sample of data and would like to find the value that would occur with 90% chance of the actual value falling short and 10% probability of exceeding actual value.

I understand how to do this by hand, but I know there is a SAS function that can do this with certain calculated inputs.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to calculate the 90th percentile?  I.e. the value that is greater than or equal to 90% of the records and less than or equal to 10% of the records?

Comment: Well my main goal is to take 20 years of weather history (the maximum temperature for each year), then calculate the temperature at which there would be 90% probability of the temperature falling below, and 10% above. I'm not sure if this is the same idea as creating percentiles on the history of temperatures, or if I should be using some sort of sample or simulation with the CDF

Comment: If you're asking how to do this sort of thing in terms of the statistical question, you should ask on [stats.se]; that's the site for statistics questions.  If you know exactly what you want to do and just want to know how to do it in SAS, here is fine, but it seems like you don't yet know exactly what you want to do. 

If you as you say know how to do it by hand, perhaps put that in the question.

Comment: Please add and example: the data you have and the desired output table so we can help you with the SAS code.

Comment: You're looking to calculate the percentiles and/or you can look at PROC UNIVARIATE to calculate the percentiles or CDFcurve.